# How do I start a repl inside of a ClojureScript page?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, clojurescript, om

I have a single page application that consists of 4,000 lines of ClojureScript.  The page is served up from a Clojure Web Server and is running inside of my browser.  What I want to do is to start a REPL inside of my page and connect to it from outside of my page.  So, do we have any browser hosted REPL's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of the basics are covered in the ClojureScript wiki [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/The-REPL-and-Evaluation-Environments#using-the-browser-as-an-evaluation-environment).

[As of 2014](https://cognitect.wufoo.com/reports/state-of-clojurescript-2014-results/) two popular browser REPLs are:

- [Austin](https://github.com/cemerick/austin)
- [Weasel](https://github.com/tomjakubowski/weasel)

A simplified façade on top of Weasel is [simple-brepl](https://github.com/james-henderson/simple-brepl).

Comment: OK, I will have to give it a go.  Thanks!